# Angular Workbox service worker Registration fails with 404 error

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, service-worker, workbox, micro-frontend

I am building a web app with a micro front end architecture. I am having trouble registering a Workbox service worker. I continue to get a 404 error for the service-worker.js file.

### Architecture

```
Web-|
    | Apps - |
    |        |- Shell -|
    |        |         L src - |
    |        |                 |- index.html
    |        |                 |- main.ts
    |        |                 L app -|
    |        |                        L app.module 
    |        |- Microapp 1
    |        L Microapp 2
    |
    |- workbox -|
    |           |- src -|
    |           |       L service-worker.ts
    |           |
    |           L webpack.config.js
    |
    |- workbox-build-inject.js
    L  workbox-config.js
```

I am using webpack to transpile a `service-worker.ts` file to a `service-worker.js` file that is placed in `dist/apps/shell/service-worker.js` which should be the root directory of my shell application.

I am then registering the Service worker in the main.ts file

```js
function registerServiceWorker() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator){
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('./service-worker.js')
            .then(reg => {
                console.log('[App] succesful service worker registration', reg);
                if (!navigator.serviceWorker.controller){
                    console.log('controller is not ready... reloading');
                    location.reload();
                }
            })
            .catch(err =>
                console.error('[App] Service worker registration failed', err)
            );
    }else{
        console.error('[App] Service Worker API is not supported in current browser');
    }
}

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then( ()=> {
        registerServiceWorker();
   })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

the Shell app runs on https://localhost:4200/#/. The error reads `service worker registration failed. 404 returned for script at https://localhost:4200/service-worker.js`

- I have checked that the service-worker.js file is in fact inside of the `dist/apps/shell/` directory (which is the same directory of all the angular transpiled files with GUID names that get injected into the cache)

#### webpack config

```js
const path = require('path');

const webBuildTargetFolder = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'app', 'shell');
console.log(` writing to  ${webBuildTargetFolder}`);
const targetServiceWorkerFilename = 'service-worker.js';

module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'none',
    entry: {
        index: path.join(__dirname, 'src',  'serviceworker.ts'),
    },
    resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
    output: {
        path: webBuildTargetFolder,
        filename: targetServiceWorkerFilename,
    },
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

#### workbox config

```js
module.exports = {
  globDirectory: "dist/apps/shell/",
  globPatterns: ["**/*.{css,eot,html,ico,jpg,js,json,png,svg,ttf,txt,webmanifest,woff,woff2,webm,xml}"],
  globFollow: true, // follow symlinks
  globStrict: true, // fail the build if anything goes wrong while reading the files
  globIgnores: [
    // Ignore Angular's ES5 bundles
    // With this, we eagerly load the es2015
    // bundles and we only load/cache the es5 bundles when requested
    // i.e., on browsers that need them
    // Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31256#issuecomment-506507021
    `**/*-es5.*.js`,
  ],
  // Look for a 20 character hex string in the file names
  // Allows to avoid using cache busting for Angular files because Angular already takes care of that!
  dontCacheBustURLsMatching: new RegExp(".+.[a-f0-9]{20}..+"),
  maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4Mb
  swSrc: "dist/apps/shell/service-worker.js",
  swDest: "dist/apps/shell/service-worker.js",
};
```

#### Why can the service-worker not be found at `https://localhost:4200/service-worker.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Add "precache": "sw-precache --verbose --config=sw-precache-config.js" to your package.json scripts object.

RUN  ng build --prod --aot
Make sure of the below:

INDEX:

```
   <script>
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('ngsw-worker.js')
   .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
   .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
   }
    </script>
```

SERVICE WORKER name (ngsw-worker) in public folder (WWW) Corresponds to INDEX: ngsw-worker.jS